# Minimize aloha js size

Tags: aloha-editor

aloha.js or aloha-full.js has code for all the plugins listed at its website.

But, I require only a few of them and doesn't want to overload the user's browser page load time.

So, is there a way to achieve it?

Thanks in anticipation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a costum build file and minify the aloha editor with just the plugins you need.

Here is a short description:
http://www.aloha-editor.org/guides/develop_aloha.html#customized-builds

However you have to get fimilar with node.js and r.js.

If this is your first time using this tool, you need about 1-2 days to make a costum aloha build (at least it took me this long)

BR,
Stefan